# Forcing a combobox to "dropdown" above instead of below

Tags: winapi, combobox, mfc, comctl32

When you click on the "dropdown" button of a combobox, the dropped down listbox appears *below* the combobox, unless there is not enough space below, in which case the listbox appears *above*.

Now I wonder if there is a possibility to force the lisbox to appear *above* the combobox, even if there is enough space below.

**Illustration**

When I click on the combo box, I'd like the "drop down" list box appear always above as on the left screen copy.

[image]

Comment: Not possible from what I know of... this is handled by the control which paints the list. Now you can always subclass that control and override the paint method...

Comment: It's how Windows handles the combo box and menus, you cannot change that. Overriding the paint or draw wont change it. You may need to write your own custom control from scratch. Drop the idea!

Answer (score 4):

Everything is possible, and you don't need to implement the control "from scratch".

First, you can subclass the ListBox part of your ComboBox to get complete control over it, as explained in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wt95892.aspx). You can create a class, derived from CListBox, using the Class Wizard. You only need to implement `WM_WINPOSITIONCHANGING` handler in it:

```
void CTopListBox::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
    CListBox::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);
    if ((lpwndpos->flags & SWP_NOMOVE) == 0)
    {
        lpwndpos->y -= lpwndpos->cy + 30;
    }
}
```

Here, for simplicity, I am moving the box up by the (heights+30). You can get the height of your ComboBox instead of my `30`.

Then you declare a member variable in your dialog class:

```
CTopListBox m_listbox;
```

and subclass it like that:

```
HBRUSH CMFCDlgDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX)
    {
        if (m_listbox.GetSafeHwnd() == NULL)
        {
            m_listbox.SubclassWindow(pWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
            CRect r;
            m_listbox.GetWindowRect(r);
            m_listbox.MoveWindow(r);
        }
    }

    HBRUSH hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    return hbr;
}
```

Note that I am calling `m_listbox.MoveWindow(r)` there; it is needed because first `WM_CONTROLCOLOR` message for that list box comes after it is positioned, so the very first time it would drop down instead of up.

Disclaimer: this is not a very clean solution, as, if you have windows animation enabled, you'd see that the list unrolls from top to bottom.

Alternatively, you should be able to "fool" the combobox that it is too close to the bottom of the screen; then it will drop up by itself. I leave it as an exercise for the readers :)

Comment: Subclassing is much easier when using GetComboBoxInfo. Also it is possible just to handle this in CBN_DROPDOWN.

Answer (score 1):

This would be relatively easy except when combo box has "slide open" effect. If you move the dropdown listbox to the top, and the combo slides open from top-to-bottom, it would look odd. So you have to disable the animation or reverse it.

In this function I call `AnimateWindow` in `OnWindowPosChanging`, it doesn't seem to cause any problems but I am not a 100% sure about it!

```
class CComboBox_ListBox : public CListBox
{
public:
    CWnd *comboBox;
    void OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS *wndpos)
    {
        CListBox::OnWindowPosChanging(wndpos);
        if (comboBox && wndpos->cx && wndpos->cy && !(wndpos->flags & SWP_NOMOVE))
        {
            CRect rc;
            comboBox->GetWindowRect(&rc);

            //if listbox is at the bottom...
            if (wndpos->y > rc.top) {
                //if there is enough room for listbox to go on top...
                if (rc.top > wndpos->cy) {
                    wndpos->y = rc.top - wndpos->cy;
                    BOOL animation;
                    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETCOMBOBOXANIMATION, 0, &animation, 0);
                    //if combobox slides open...
                    if (animation) {
                        //we have to set the x coordinate otherwise listbox 
                        //is in the wrong place when parent window moves
                        SetWindowPos(0, wndpos->x, wndpos->y, 0, 0, 
                            SWP_NOSENDCHANGING | SWP_HIDEWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE);

                        AnimateWindow(100, AW_VER_NEGATIVE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

Usage:

```
COMBOBOXINFO ci = { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };
comboBox.GetComboBoxInfo(&ci);
CComboBox_ListBox *listBox = new CComboBox_ListBox;
listBox->comboBox = &comboBox;
listBox->SubclassWindow(ci.hwndList);
```

Also you can use `SetMinVisibleItems` to reduce the listbox height and make sure the dropdown list fits on top.

Comment: `OnWindowPosChanging` is called for many reasons (activate, etc.); you need to check `SWP_NOMOVE` flag to see if the size is changing.

Comment: @Vlad I test `cx` and `cy`, I think that's the same thing. I added `SWP_NOMOVE` test to be sure

Comment: Testing just a position is NOT enough - if the flag `SWP_NOMOVE` is set, they may be 0.