# Combo box in a MFC application

Tags: combobox, mfc, dropdown

My question is about combo boxes in Windows MFC applications.

The dropdown part of the combo box contains items composed of a bitmap and a string.

Sometimes, the strings are too long and I have to adjust the width of the dropdown part of the combo box using the `CComboBox::SetDroppedWidth()` method.

My problem is that when the combo box is near the right edge of the computer screen, the right part of the dropdown is hidden (see `image_1` and `image_2` below).

I would like it to behave like in Excel (see `image_3` below) meaning I would like the dropdown list to be shifted accordingly so that all its items can be seen without being cropped.

How can this be achieved?

***image_1: right part of the dropdown is NOT hidden***
[image: right part of the dropdown is NOT hidden]

***image_2: near the computer right edge, the right part of the dropdown is hidden***
[image: right part of the dropdown is hidden]

***image_3: Excel combo box***
[image: Excel combo box]

=================================================================

EDIT 1
[image: handles are null]

=================================================================

EDIT 2

Ok. I forgot to mention that `m_cbXmodels` is a `CComboBoxEx` object. This is why the handles are NULL. I could get the handles via `GetComboBoxCtrl()`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing a combobox to "dropdown" above instead of below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307412/forcing-a-combobox-to-dropdown-above-instead-of-below)

Answer (score 3):

Handle the `CBN_DROPDOWN` notification.

Get the handle for the list control with `GetComboBoxInfo`.

Now use MoveWindow to adjust the window as needed.

Getting the current screen size is available with `MonitorFromWindow`. See `rcWork` member in `MONITORINFO`. You just need to adjust the left and right coordinates.

**EDIT:** As you can read in the comments: My Approach with CBN_DROPDOWN is to early Thanks to zett42). It is not possible to resize the combo box list part here. 
But it is possible to post a user defined message to the same window and to reposition the window than.

Comment: Thank you. When I call GetComboBoxInfo(), I notice that the handle for the list control is NULL (hwndCombo, hwndItem and hwndList are NULL).

Comment: You must preset the cbSize member!

Comment: New problem: the dropdown list doesn't move. The code is: HWND hwndList = info.hwndList; ::MoveWindow(hwndList, 40, 40, 100, 100, 1);

Comment: @LéaMassiot From MSDN reference of `CBN_DROPDOWN`: _Sent when the list box of a combo box is *about* to be made visible._ - so `MoveWindow` propably comes to early. Try to do a `PostMessage(WM_APP + n)`, add a message map entry for `WM_APP + n` and do the `MoveWindow` in your handler of this message. This should schedule your `MoveWindow` after the combobox has done the default positioning of the listbox.

Comment: It sounds to me that the combo box class should really be updated by default to do this anyway.